# Android - document.write() blocks Google Ads - Doubleclick

Tags: javascript, android, double-click, document.write

I've found numerous questions about document.write() but none that responds to my specific problem.

### Short explanation

The request to receive an ad from DoubleClick finishes successfully but the ad doesn't load (blank space instead of seeing an ad), these are the warnings provided by logcat in Android Studio :

```
A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, SCRIPT_PATH, is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console message. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.

The SSL certificate used to load resources from WEBSITE_PATH will be distrusted in the future. Once distrusted, users will be prevented from loading these resources. See https://g.co/chrome/symantecpkicerts for more information. SCRIPT_PATH
```

### Longer Version

I have an Android app in which we include Google Ads with the DoubleClick library. Those ads can`t load on some newer devices (ex Android 7.0). I suspect that newer versions of Android have newer versions of Chromium (55+) in which the handling of document.write() has changed.
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Thus, when loading some ads (in my case all of them) I always receive the warning about document.write() and the ad doesn't load.

- I don't have any error from double click (request is successful).
- I don't have any message saying that no ads are available to be served(ad is received correctly in the request).

The only problem is the ad doesn't load because of the JavaScript it's trying to execute.

Changing the JavaScript directly doesn't sound like a good idea as it is loading in a WebView provided by an external library which would require some ugly reflection.

Classes used :

- com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
- com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest
- com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdRequest.Builder

I repeat that it works with older devices (Android 4.4 I think)